# android tracking- how to pass external param to app?

Tags: android, apk, user-tracking, install-referrer

I'm playing with my apk. I'd like to fire a conversion back on app install but don't know how to pass the unique conversion ID to the app.

Here's what I'd like to do.

1. user installs apk with his click ID: 
   http://www.example.com/myapk.apk?click=dfsg-fdsfwe-43fsdf-43sdf
2. the click parameter is fired on app start

   ```
   Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://mytracker.com/click=dfsg-fdsfwe-43fsdf-43sdf");
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```

Please point me in the right direction. If there's a better way to go at it let me know.

p.s. using adjust.com as my in app tracker, but I didn't see how they help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play provides checking install referrer function.

- Make your app that has `BroadcastReceiver` which react with action `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER`.
- User installs from link like `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.app.id&referrer=referrer_string`.
- Your BroadcastReceiver is invoked and you can get `referrer_string`

  ```
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
  }
  ```